# 'A project with output type of class library cannot be started directly'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I created new unit test project and and trying to test some links with selenium webdriver, but I am getting this error. When I change output type to console or windows, I get 'Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point'. Please help me fix this

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace billingtest

{
    [TestClass]
    public class test
    {
        FirefoxDriver driver;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void SyncDriver()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginToBilling()
    {

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:57862");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserNameOrEmail")).SendKeys("aa");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("aa");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='main']/form/div[3]/input")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='content-main']/div/div/a[3]")).Click();
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
    public static IList<IWebElement> LinkElements { get; set; }


    public void LoopLink()
    {
        int count = LinkElements.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[i].Click();
        }

    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why did you change the output type?  There's no need to do that.  You just run the tests using the 'Run test' button.  I suggest you review the documentation!

Comment: I found it as a solution somewhere, to try and change output type.

Comment: In short, pressing the run button attempts to compile the current project and execute it. Some types of project (class libraries, unit tests, etc) aren't designed to run as standalone applications, but to support other project types and thus can't be run that way. Changing the project type is an attempt to convert it into an executable - so it's asking where it should start executing code (the `Main()` method). I personally find the simplest shortcut is `CTRL-R-A` which runs all tests

Comment: @ŽygimantasDirma well that would only work if you accidentally created the wrong project type, like a "Class Library Project", where you actually need a "Console Application". In all other cases, that solution does more harm than good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a unit test, put your cursor on the test method and click on the "Run Tests in Current Context" button (also in the 'Test' menu in VS).

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524(v=vs.90).aspx.

You should also add some validation to your test method, so that VS can report whether it passed or failed.  Add something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(outcome);
```

where `outcome` is a boolean that indicates the success of your test method.